# @karate How to pass parameter to a feature file in gatling simulation class?

Tags: scala, karate

Let's consider a scenario, we have to run the performance test for "create an account api" which takes input as header/path param "Auth token" and input data like user account name . So for above scenario we have 2 feature file as,

to run performance test for POST **http://baseUrl/auth_param/create/input_data** 
 1. One feature(e.g: generateAuth.feature) file which will have the auth
    token
 2. Second feature(createAccount.feature) file which take parameter as a
    auth token, input data.

Here is my simulation class,

```
class <MyClass> extends Simulation {

  before {
    println("Simulation is about to start!")
  }
  val generateAuthTest = scenario("generateAuth").exec(karateFeature("classpath:path/generateAuth.feature")) 
  val createAccountTest = scenario("test").exec(karateFeature("classpath:path/createAccount.feature"))
  setUp(
    createAccountTest.inject(rampUsers(1) over (10 seconds))).maxDuration(1 minutes)
  after {
    println("Simulation is finished!")
  }
}
```

**Here, can i read auth from generateAuth.feature file which is input for createAccount.feature file, so that i can pass as a parameter?**
Please suggest me how to pass parameters to createAccount.feature while calling in karateFeature method.

Let me put a requirement here,

let's say we have some feature files for CRUD operations on a particular data. Here how i go to write functional scenario,

1. I will create new feature file to write a scenario
2. just use CRUD files to test a SINGLE flow.

Now if i go for Performance test cases on individual operation, i feel there are 2 ways,

1. Create new 4 performance test feature files (one for each CRUD
   method) and call these CRUD feature files in the respective test
   feature file. Finally we just call test feature files in the
   respective gatling simulation class.
       **(In this case, I will end up with creating more test feature files as well simulation classes for
       performance, which I want to avoid) **
2. Just call CRUD files in the respective gatling simulation class  and
           pass the required parameters to them.**(In this case , we just need to create only 4 simulation
           classes and run them on the basic of operation like create,read,delete and so on)**

**Here just wanted to know 2nd way of performance test, is it achievable or not in karate and if yes please let me know how?**

> Summary- I think its achievable using 3rd feature file (extra) for
>   individual use case but I do not want to make an extra feature file
>   for each case so that I can avoid maintenance work and can take
>   advantage of re-usability of existing feature file from functional
>   test to performance test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the normal Karate concepts such as [`karate-config.js`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration)

You can easily [switch environments](https://github.com/intuit/karate#switching-the-environment) by setting the `karate.env` system property.

For example:

`mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=e2e"`

EDIT: after you edited your question, it is clear you have a SINGLE flow you want to test. please use a SINGLE feature. I suggest you move the `generateAuth` into the `Background` of the feature. Also refer to the docs on `callSingle()` for advanced options.

If you are expecting 2 feature files to magically share data that is not possible and not needed if you structure your tests correctly.

If you really really need this, please create a Java singleton and access it from each feature. Totally don't recommend this though.

EDIT: In Karate 0.9.0 onwards, you can [call a single scenario within a feature if it has a tag](https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector):

```
classpath:animals/cats/create.feature@sometagname
```

Comment: Here i was not referring for something change in cmd line arg. i was expecting some way to pass parameters for feature file in simulation class it self. I have edited my question for better understanding. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: @ManojMishra are you new to Karate and jumped straight into perf-testing ? anyway please read my edit.

Comment: Hi peter, Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question again and added one requirement why i specifically need this. Please let me know if i miss something to make you understand.

Comment: Thank You for creating a git ticket for it.

Comment: @ManojMishra no problem. I got confused with the term "parameter" but I think I got it now. please discuss on GitHub