# Is there any way to update the values of the feature file from the internally called feature file

Tags: karate

My requirement is:

A.feature:

```
Background:
* def login = call read('login.feature')
* access_token = login.access_token

Scenario:
* def bookings = call read('fetchBookings.feature') { access_token: '#(access_token)' }
* def cancelBookings = call read('cancelBooking.feature') { access_token: '#(access_token)' }
.
.
.
.
. etc
```

fetchBookings.feature:

```
Scenario:
    * def parameters = { access_token: '#(access_token)' }
    * url baseUrl
    And path path
    And header authorization = parameters.access_token
    And request parameters.data
    When method method
    Then status 200
    * def responseObject = responseStatus == 401 ? utils.refeshToken({refresh_token: parameters.refresh_token, url: graphURL, path: '', headers: parameters.headers, data: parameters.data, method: 'post' }) : { response: response, status: responseStatus }
    * def response = responseObject.response
    Then match responseObject.status == 200
```

Here I will get status code 401, If access_token is expired. I will call refresh token HTTP request and will get the fresh token. There are 10 to 15 calls to different feature files in the A.feature file. Can you please suggest to me a way to update the refresh token variable in the A.feature file? I need to use the updated access_token value to call different feature files from the A.feature file.

Since there is no chance to update the karate-config.js file to set the values globally.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this stack overflow. Anyway, I have done accepting to my previous question.

Comment: short answer - write a java singleton and call it from all features.https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505847/143475

Comment: Peter, I am not using the maven structure for running the test cases. I am using the karate zip structure, i.e karate jar file to run the feature files. I am new to this java, can you suggest to me a better way of adding a java singleton class.

Comment: in that case I suggest please don't overcomplicate things. use `karate.callSingle()` (see links above) and use the same token for all features. or if you don't mind making the token call all the time, use `call` like you are already doing. and if really needed you should be able to figure out some JS logic to use the test start-time and refresh the token only after some time. other than that I have no other suggestions